# How to test nested React components?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have the following situation where I have the following functionality I'd like to test, however, I can't seem to locate in the debug statements nor Enzyme's docs on how to achieve this:

```
wrapper = mount(
      <SampleProvider data={data}>
        <App />
      </SampleProvider>
);
```

and I have App wrapped in a higher order function as follows:

```
  @applyData
  class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return <div>App</div>
    }
  }
```

I'd like to first, test whether applyData is correctly passing data in as props and the ability to check other conditions, etc. In short, the provider sets data inside of context and applyData basically passes the data as props into the wrapped component.

I've tried mount, shallow, etc... however, I can't get the information I need with any of the following:

```
wrapper.find(App)
wrapper.children()
wrapper.instance()
```